# Titanium Studio JavaScript - TableView/App.properties

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

Right so i have a new problem, I trying to save a table view with app.properties after i push another piece of data into that tableview. Below is how i create the table view and how i think i should save it. Underneath that is how im pushing the data to that table.

```
    Ti.App.Properties.getString("TableData");
var customTableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    BackgroundColor:'White',
    style: Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED,

    search:search,
    searchHidden:false, 
    data:[
    {title:"Toms List", value: true},
    {title:"Shopping List", value: true},
    {title:"Jocelyns List", value: true},
    {title:"Friday List", value: true}
    ]

});
Ti.App.Properties.setString("TableData", customTableView);




 ProductsDone.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    Ti.App.Properties.setString("lastwin", 'SavedList');
    ProductsNav.close();
    Products.close();
    SavedList.open();
    SavedListNav.open();

var data = customTableView.data;
data.push({title: Products.title, value: true});
customTableView.data = data;
});
```

Comment: I'd update the question with the problem you have and any error message.

Comment: @phil thats the problem it just produce an error message, it just doesn't work.

Comment: ok, i'm not sure why you need to save a tableview to app proprties, can't you just save the data? Or have you tried using setObject instead of setString?

Comment: Are you working from an example app?  Saving the table object to app properties doesn't make much sense to me, even with setObject.